# How can I make my outer for loop iterate past i = 1?

Tags: c

The code is meant to make 3 2D arrays (3x3). ar1 consists of 1s, ar2 has diagonal components equal to 2, and 0 otherwise. ar3 is the sum of each corresponding index of ar1 and ar2. I've used a nested for loop for this but for some reason the outer for loop iterates continuously for i =1. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 2 

int main(void)
  {
  int i = 0, j, ar1[2][2], ar2[2][2], ar3[2][2];

  for(i = 0; i<=SIZE; i++)
    {
    for(j = 0; j<=SIZE; j++)
      {
      ar1[i][j] = 1;

      if(i == j)
        ar2[i][j] = 2;
      else
        ar2[i][j] = 0;

      ar3[i][j] = ar1[i][j] + ar2[i][j];

      printf("%-4d", ar3[i][j]);
      }

    printf("\n");
    }

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `for(i = 0; i<=SIZE; i++)` undefined behaviour, should be `for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)` or you access outside bounds.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No, it is absolutely defined behaviour, loop executes 3 timnes. Agree, condition should be like You say.

Comment: You say your arrays are 3x3, but your code contains the line ` #define SIZE 2 `.  These two facts seem incompatible.

Comment: You probably want to say `int ar1[SIZE][SIZE], ar2[SIZE][SIZE], ar3[SIZE][SIZE];`.

Comment: I suggest that you add the line `printf("i = %d\n", i);` immediately before `for(j = 0; j<=SIZE; j++)`. Then you will see precisely what value `i` is taking on. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code accesses the array out of bounds when `i == SIZE`

```
 int i = 0, j, ar1[2][2], ar2[2][2], ar3[2][2];

   for(i = 0; i<=SIZE; i++)
   {
     for(j = 0; j<=SIZE; j++)
     {
        ar1[i][j] = 1;
```

what happens is *undefined behaviour*.

In your case, by what you're describing, by writing outside `ar` memory, you're overwriting `i` or `j` with the value `1` which resets the index to `1` (arrays are probably located *before* the index variables by the compiler). That'd explain it.

So the fix is

```
 int i = 0, j, ar1[SIZE][SIZE], ar2[SIZE][SIZE], ar3[SIZE][SIZE];

   for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
   {
     for(j = 0; j<SIZE; j++)
     {
        ar1[i][j] = 1;
```

and so on ... (note that if you define `SIZE` as `2`, better use it also to initialize your arrays)

BTW if you want to make 3x3 arrays you have to set `SIZE` to `3`

```
#define SIZE 3
```

so first valid index is 0 and last valid index is 2

Answer (score 3):

In any programming language, there are basically two ways of writing a "for i in 1 to N loop":

```
for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)    /* "one-based" */

for(i = 0; i < N; i++)     /* "zero-based" */
```

Learn this early and learn this well: In C, 0-based loops are vastly preferred.  This is closely related to the fact that C uses 0-based arrays.  You will occasionally see a 1-based loop, but it's rare, and will only occur when you're doing something special.  But initializing some ordinary arrays is not special.

Whenever you see a loop that doesn't match one of the above two patterns, such as

```
for(i = 1; i < N; i++)      /* questionable */

for(i = 0; i <= N; i++)     /* questionable */
```

it should be a sign to you that something even more unusual -- and probably wrong -- is going on.  The loop `for(i = 1; i < N; i++)` makes a total of N-1 trips.  The loop `for(i = 0; i <= N; i++)` makes a total of N+1 trips.

If you are iterating over an array of size SIZE, you always want to use the

```
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
```

form, because the array's indices run from 0 to SIZE-1.

By allowing the loop to run up to `i=SIZE`, you access memory outside of the array.  Specifically: since `SIZE` is 2, the valid indices are just 0 and 1.  When you set `i` or `j` to 2, you're accessing memory outside the array.

In this case, by accessing memory outside of the array, it's likely that you are inadvertently overwriting the `i` and/or `j` variables.  (Specifically, you might be setting `i` or `j` back to 0 or 1, meaning that it never gets up to SIZE.) That's probably why the loop is running forever.